# Redirect all subfolders of a language to the language folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect all subfolders of a language to the language folder. For example :

- `http://example.com/es/folder1/`
- `http://example.com/es/folder1/folder2/`

redirect to `http://example.com/es/`

I tried different options such as

```
Redirectmatch 301 ^es/(.*)$ www.example.com/es/$1
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ www.example.com/es/$1
```

but as the parent folder is the same as destination folder, it was doing a loop.

Comment: I had to remove the "http://" in front in order to post this question

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirectmatch 301 ^/es/(.+)$ www.example.com/es/
```

`$1` is the back-reference to `(.+)`. I think you are redirecting `/es/(.+)` to `/es/`, you can drop the `$1`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer. works like a charm!